# Ruby convention - uppercase selector?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

As far as I know, Ruby has some convention on letter capitalization. Does it have any convention about `:UPPERCASE_SELECTORS`?

Comment: `CONSTANTS_ARE_LIKE_THIS`. As far as "selectors" (which is really just a Symbol, often used for message names or keys), can't say I've seen any .. is it used in a particular code-base or example?

Comment: @pst I don't have any. I just want to use uppercase selector for my new code, and just wanted to confirm about conventional validity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the language or the community?

In the language, there is nothing that prevents you from using any Unicode character you want in a method name and/or a message selector. It might not be possible to define them via `def` or call them via `.`, but it *is* possible using reflection.

If you want to define them via `def` or call them with `.`, then there is still a lot of room: the name needs to start with an underscore or a letter (Unicode letters are perfectly fine, i.e. `µ` is a perfectly valid method name), followed by an arbitrary number of letters, numbers and underscores and optionally ending with either a question mark, exclamation mark or equals sign.

Starting with an uppercase letter, containing uppercase letters or even being completely uppercase is perfectly valid.

It is, however, not idiomatic. Not usually, anyway. Idiomatic method names are `snake_case`, i.e. starting with a lowercase letter and consisting of lowercase words separated by underscores, containing only ASCII characters.

There are exceptions, however. In particular, methods that are intended as factory companions for specific classes may have the same name as the corresponding class. For example, the `Kernel#Array`, `Kernel#Hash`, `Kernel#String`, `Kernel#Float` and `Kernel#Integer` methods that turn their argument into, well, an array, hash, string, float or integer.

Another exception are methods that are intended to be used like parametric classes, like the `Object#DelegateClass` method from the `delegate` library in the stdlib which takes a class and returns a wrapper class for that class, so that it can be used like this:

```
class MyArray < DelegateClass(Array); end
```